# Read data from serial port device in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

We need to weigh a bunch of products, and store their weight in a DB.
We have a scale that can be plugged through a serial port, and then we want to scan the product's barcode with a barcode scanner.

I need to write a program that will read the scale data. I have read and followed a bunch of articles on how to do it, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Weighting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        public Form1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.port.Open();

            this.port.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
            this.port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            this.port.RtsEnable = true;
            this.port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;

            this.port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.port_DataReceived);
        }

        ~Form1()
        {
            this.port.Close();
            this.port.Dispose();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                char[] data = new char[] { 's', ' ', '\r', '\n' };
                this.port.Write(data, 0, 1);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                var InputData = this.port.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputData))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(InputData);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            var InputData = this.port.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(InputData);
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

The `DataReceived` handler is never fired, and `ReadLine()` never returns anything.

The specs of the scale can be found here (chapter 10) : http://www.kern-sohn.com/manuals/files/English/FCB-BA-e-0911.pdf

Note that it's very possible that my serial port, or my cable don't work, or that the scale doesn't send data, or whatever (it's been about 15 years since I have used a serial port device). How can y test that everything works ?

Thank you!

## Update

The connection parameters have been taken (and interpreted) from an old Excel macro:

```
With MSComm1
    .CommPort = 1
    .Handshaking = 0
    .RThreshold = 1
    .RTSEnable = True
    .Settings = "9600,n,8,1"
    .SThreshold = 1
    .PortOpen = True
End With
```

This macro supposedly used to work a few years back, but I couldn't make it work myself (the MSComm1 object is not defined).

Comment: Can you connect with something like hyperterminal and determine if the balance is sending you anything at all? Does it send data continuously? Or do you have to send it a command to request data? Or to put it into continuous mode?

Comment: I have installed hyperterminal but I don't know much how to use it. From the specs, I gather that I must send "w" or "s" ("without a subsequent CR LF") and it sends the weight. Hyperterminal gets me nothing, but then again I don't know if I'm using it correctly.

Comment: If you can get some data using hyperterminal, then it might be a problem with the device, the cable or the port (probably USB/Serial adapter I'm guessing). Or maybe the connection parameters are wrong (a mistake in a manual isn't unheard of).

Comment: The cable is plugged into a real serial port, but the cable itself comes from God know where (I couldn't find another). The connection parameters have been taken from an old Excel macro, I'll update the question.

Comment: Try to connect Rx pin with Tx pin and write anything in hyperterminal. I think this is shortest way to determine if your port and cable are ok. It is also important, what kind of cable do you have, null-modem ?

Comment: @user3894601: Thank you, I had totally forgotten about straight and crossed cables. I'll try to find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @user3894601, the problem was solved by using the original cable, and using a USB adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection setup looks to match the documentation, but your code smells quite a bit (this is nothing against you, the .NET `SerialPort` is a nightmare to work with!).

You are not setting the `SerialPort.NewLine` property to `Environment.NewLine` (CRLF) and it is instead using the default value of `\n` (LF). This alone doesn't solve the problem, because you would just have a carriage return at end of the result of  calling `ReadLine()`.

The real issue is the `DataReceived` handler. A lot of people recommend using it but through my exhaustive testing it diminishes determinism of results greatly, particularly when communicating in a friendly encoding such as ASCII. Because you initiate the command by sending your `s` character, I would honestly get rid of it, and just call `ReadLine()` right after your `Write`. (You do not need to `Thread.Sleep` because `ReadLine` will simply block until the terminated string is read in or a timeout is reached).

Your `ReceivedBytesThreshold` is set to 1, and that specifies the buffer size to fill before raising `DataReceived` so you're trying to read a whole line for every byte received (give or take, `DataReceived` is very unpredictable).

Here's an example of how I would clean it up (in addition to removing the `DataReceived` handler). I can't be certain if this will clear your problem up, but making these corrections will lead to much easier debugging. As a temporary change to aid with debugging, you could bring your Sleep call back in and call `ReadExisting` instead of `ReadLine` and examine what it pulls (if anything) from the buffer.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.port.Write("s");
        var InputData = this.port.ReadLine();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InputData))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(InputData);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I've just finished writing a library to sit on top of the .NET SerialPort for my company and have run into the same sort of issues (plus a million more) as you. If you would like further clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks! Your code indeed works (and is more simple), even though that wasn't the problem.